# The specificity of sorting

Tags: c#, .net

Code of the character `'-'` is 45, code of the character `'a'` is 97. It's clear that `'-' < 'a'` is true.

```
Console.WriteLine((int)'-' + " " + (int)'a');
Console.WriteLine('-' < 'a');
```

> 45 97
>   True

Hence the result of the following sort is correct

```
var a1 = new string[] { "a", "-" };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", a1));
Array.Sort(a1);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", a1));
```

> a -
>   - a

But why the result of the following sort is wrong?

```
var a2 = new string[] { "ab", "-b" };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", a2));
Array.Sort(a2);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", a2));
```

> ab -b
>   ab -b

Comment: I found that `StringComparer.Ordinal` solves the problem. But still it's weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-` is ignored,

```
so - = "" < a
and -b = "b" > "ab"
```

this is because of Culture sort ( which is default )

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions(v=vs.110).aspx

> ```
> The .NET Framework uses three distinct ways of sorting: word sort, string
> ```
>
> sort, and ordinal sort. Word sort performs a culture-sensitive
>   comparison of  strings. Certain nonalphanumeric characters might have
>   special weights assigned  to them. For example, the hyphen ("-") might
>   have a very small weight assigned  to it so that "coop" and "co-op"
>   appear next to each other in a sorted list.  String sort is similar to
>   word sort, except that there are no special cases.  Therefore, all
>   nonalphanumeric symbols come before all alphanumeric characters. 
>   Ordinal sort compares strings based on the Unicode values of each
>   element of the  string.

Comment: Why ignored? It's not obvious.

Comment: updated...   hyphens in words are considered non significant ( based on culture)